# Stack trace:\sshd.exe: *** fatal error - could not load u, Win32 error 1114,COPSSH GIT TORTOISEGIT

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit

I have this very strange situation using git and copssh with key authentication.

When I do git push or clone using tortoisegit or git extension with key authentication it always failed with

> Stack trace:\sshd.exe: *** fatal error
>   - could not load u, Win32 error 1114

But when I load the same key using putty it works okay. I did try to change tortoisegit ssh client using plink.exe still not work.

I tried to change authentication method using password after i delete authorized_key file from home/user/.ssh directory and all git commands works okay.

So what makes it all wrong ?
Please help...

TIA

Answer (score 4):

It turns out about permissions, I am using COPSSH and it use windows user name as ssh account. When you authenticate using password you dont have to be administrator to have permissions to clone (read) or push (write) but when you authenticate using pair key you need to have administrator privileges even though you had set full control permissions to your destination folder.